# Memory leak in docker

Tags: docker, memory-leaks

I have an application that uses shared memory, while running application we occupy some shared memory and when we kill the process we release those memory like we are suppose to do.

The question I am wondering is when I am running this application inside `docker` container and if docker itself is killed say using `docker kill docker_id`. I have seen that SIGINT of process is not called sometime and container just got killed and removed.

I want to understand what happens to shared memory I allocated in my application if docker itself is removed which properly closing the app.

Will this result in memory leak or docker take care of it itself and memory is released. Is there any way I can handle this if there is an actual memory leak happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`docker kill`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/kill/) sends a signal to the main process running in a container, the same way as the normal Unix **kill**(1) command.  Note, though, that `docker kill` normally sends `SIGKILL`, the same as shell `kill -9`; a process can't observe `SIGKILL` or react to it in any way, it's just immediately killed off.

So, yes, it's possible that `docker kill container_id` will cause a leak of system resources, in the same way that `kill -9 process_id` would without Docker.

It's more common to [`docker stop`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/stop/) a container.  When you do,

> The main process inside the container will receive `SIGTERM`, and after a grace period, `SIGKILL`.

So long as you subscribe to `SIGTERM` and do your cleanup promptly (the default timeout is 10 seconds) this should avoid the resource leak.

You can also specify an alternate signal to `docker kill` but it wouldn't necessarily be my default approach here

```bash
docker kill --signal=SIGINT container_id
```

Comment: Thanks, so if I understand it correctly if docker is killed and we haven't freed the memory then that will be part of host machine and may create issue until we restart the system..right?

Comment: It should be the same thing as if you `kill -9` the same process running outside a container.  And it'd be specific to some system-level resources, just ordinary "memory" would be freed when the process exits.